# How to mimic this bar-chart style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, bar-chart

Recently I had to redraw a bar-chart in a style similar to the screenshot, using black, white and gray. Obviously, none of the available packages supports this style.

How to do it, e.g. with `pstricks` or `tikz`?

[image: Bar-chart style to be mimicked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using package `pstricks`. The **basic idea** is to forget about the data and translate them into some length. Here, I simply turn them into centimeters, i.e. dividing by 10.000: 24.000 becomes 2.4cm . Place everything manually.

So I draw horizontal lines for the grid and label them via a node. // All bars are just **thick lines**; highlighted bars are similar with a different linecolor; so are the actual and reference bars in black. // The values for the black bars are indicated with a simple 3-point line and \rput. // Finally date and weekend-days are put below the chart using \rput.

My Quick Build **compile options** in Miktex have to include dvips and ps2pdf, as for any other pstricks compile I do.

To use this diagramm in other documents, I just use `\includegraphics` from package `graphicx` with a proper setting of the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0, -1)(12, 4)
      % ~~~ grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \psset{linecolor = gray!50}
        \psline     (2, 2.4)(10, 2.4)
        \rput [r] (1.5, 2.4) {24.000}
        
        \psline     (2, 1.8)(10, 1.8)
        \rput [r] (1.5, 1.8) {18.000}
        
        \psline     (2, 1.2)(10, 1.2)
        \rput [r] (1.5, 1.2) {12.000}
        
        \psline     (2, 0.6)(10, 0.6)
        \rput [r] (1.5, 0.6) {6.000}
        
        \psline     (2, 0)(10, 0)
        \rput [r] (1.5, 0) {0}
        
      % ~~~ bars ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \psset{linewidth = 3mm, linecolor = gray}

        % ~~~ regular bars ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \psline (2.2, 0)(2.2, 1.99)
        \psline (2.7, 0)(2.7, 2.15)
        \psline (4.2, 0)(4.2, 1.34)
        \psline (4.7, 0)(4.7, 1.53)
        \psline (5.2, 0)(5.2, 1.85)
        \psline (7.7, 0)(7.7, 1.08)
        \psline (8.2, 0)(8.2, 1.44)
        \psline (8.7, 0)(8.7, 1.76)
        \psline (6.2, 0)(6.2, 2.35)

        % ~~~ weekend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \psline [linecolor=gray!50](3.2, 0)(3.2, 2.34)
        \psline [linecolor=gray!50](3.7, 0)(3.7, 1.60)
        \psline [linecolor=gray!50](6.7, 0)(6.7, 2.25)
        \psline [linecolor=gray!50](7.2, 0)(7.2, 1.69)


        % ~~~ highlighted bars, with 3-point line + values ~~~
        \psline [linecolor=black] (5.7, 0)(5.7, 2.19)
         \psline [linewidth = 1 pt] (4.7, 2.3)(5.7, 2.3)(5.7, 2.2)
        \rput [r] (5.7, 2.5) {21.866}


        \psline [linecolor=black] (9.2, 0)(9.2, 2.26)
         \psline [linewidth = 1 pt] (8.2, 2.4)(9.2, 2.4)(9.2, 2.3)
        \rput [r] (9.2, 2.6) {22.609}
        
      % ~~~ date ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \rput (2.2, -6 mm) {5.November}
        \rput (5.7, -6 mm) {12.November}
        \rput (9.2, -6 mm) {19.November}
        
      % ~~~ weekend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \rput (3.2, -3 mm){Sa}
        \rput (3.7, -3 mm){So}
        \rput (6.7, -3 mm){Sa}
        \rput (7.2, -3 mm){So}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using package `tikz`. The **basic idea** is to forget about the data and translate them into some length. Here, I simply turn them into centimeters, i.e. dividing by 10.000: 24.000 becomes 2.4cm . Place everything manually.

So I draw horizontal lines for the grid and label them via a node. // The regular bars are a series of **plotted [ybar]s**; highlighted bars are similar with a different fill color; so are the actual and reference bars in black. // Finally date and weekend-days are put as nodes below the chart. // I left out putting values above the black bars, while it’s straight forward to do in tikz.

My Quick Build compile options in Miktex are the same as for any other Latex-document I compile.

To use this diagramm in other documents, I just use `\includegraphics` from package `graphicx` with a proper setting of the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ybar]
      % ~~~ Grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (10, 2.4) -- (1.5, 2.4) node(xline) [left] {$24.000$};
        \draw (10, 1.8) -- (1.5, 1.8) node(xline) [left] {$18.000$};
        \draw (10, 1.2) -- (1.5, 1.2) node(xline) [left] {$12.000$};
        \draw (10, 0.6) -- (1.5, 0.6) node(xline) [left] {$6.000$};
        \draw (10, 0.0) -- (1.5, 0.0) node(xline) [left] {$0.000$};
    
      % ~~~ bars ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[color=gray, fill=gray, bar width=3mm] 
            plot coordinates{(2.2, 1.99)(2.7, 2.15) 
            (4.2, 1.34)(4.7, 1.53)(5.2, 1.85)
            (6.2, 2.35)(7.7, 1.08)(8.2, 1.44)(8.7, 1.76) };
      % ~~~ highlighted bars ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[color=gray!50, fill=gray!50, bar width=3mm] 
            plot coordinates{(3.2, 2.34) (3.7, 1.60)
            (6.7, 2.25)(7.2, 1.69)};
      % ~~~ actual + the week before ~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw[color=black, fill=black, bar width=3mm] 
            plot coordinates{(5.7, 2.19)(9.2, 2.26)};
            
      % ~~~ date ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (2.2, -6 mm) node{5.November};
        \draw (5.7, -6 mm) node{12.November};
        \draw (9.2, -6 mm) node{19.November};
      
      % ~~~ weekend ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \draw (3.2, -3 mm) node{Sa};
        \draw (3.7, -3 mm) node{So};
        
        \draw (6.7, -3 mm) node{Sa};
        \draw (7.2, -3 mm) node{So};
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]