# Insert a scalable graphic which doesn't affect file size too much

Tags: graphics, pdf, overleaf, includegraphics, svg

At the moment I've inserted graphics into my document using .png. This works good but the graphics are too blurry. To avoid this, I wanted to use a scalable file format like .pdf or .svg.

Using .pdf results in blurry graphics also and takes ages to compile the document... What is the best way to insert a scalable graphic into an Overleaf document? So far my search results on google haven't helped

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.6cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

test
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{test11.pdf}
  \centering
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

to download the .pdf: https://ufile.io/nli4gy5z

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // What kind of graphics do you talk about? Photos, or scientific drawings? The latter one are best created as vector graphics (.ps, or .eps, of .pdf) using packages like PSTricks or tikz. Vector graphics are scalable without quality loss.

Comment: Many graphics such as plots, charts, or diagrams can be made in LaTeX itself using various packages, which is not blurry (although some pdf viewers may have trouble at certain zoom levels). For external vector graphics the PDF format is usually the best, both in terms of file size/processing time and in terms of quality. However, it is important that the PDF file indeed contains actual vector graphics, if it is just a PNG file embedded in a PDF then it will be blurred and with a larger file size. So you need to make sure to produce the PDF using a program that actually outputs vector graphics.

Comment: @MS-SPO I'm talking about plots. For some reason including a graphic as .pdf takes really long to compile the document.

Also when inserting the .pdf scatterplots look blurry?

Comment: @Marijn 
my plots are generated  in matplotlib and I've exported them as .pdf and .svg.
So it should be a "real" .pdf...
But still it takes really long to compile the document as well as scatter plots look blurry

Comment: @learnPyt, may be it's time to post a concrete example, which a) conatins your problem, b) can be copied and compiled by us. Thanks // See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615111/how-to-mimic-this-bar-chart-style to create some .ps or .pdf, which you can `\include` in your Latex-document.

Comment: @MS-SPO 
I've edited my question.... unfortunately I can't upload the .pdf I'm using... any idea how I could share this?

Comment: @learnPyt : fine :) About the .pdf, it depends, what's in it. If you created a plot e.g. with tikz or PSTricks I'd just post that code as well. It's a simple copy&compile, then ;-) Else look for one of those public clouds, upload and post the link here.

Comment: @MS-SPO
I've just updated my post adding the link to the pdf.
The pdf is available at
https://ufile.io/nli4gy5z

Comment: On my system when compiling your code with the `test11.pdf` file from your link, using pdflatex, and viewing with Evince on Ubuntu, the result is very clear. However, it takes unusually long (a couple of seconds) to render the pdf, and when I zoom it is blurry at first and then becomes sharp again after a few seconds. So my guess is that your viewer also struggles with the plot, maybe resulting in a blurry graphic. However, it seems you have a _lot_ of points in the plot, which obviously are not all visible in the output because they overlap.

Comment: Maybe you can find a way to reduce the number of points without changing the visible result? That would make the whole process faster and easier on the viewer, and possibly resolve the blur issue.

Answer (score 1):

To check for the speed issue I commented out, what's not needed right away, with some corrections:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.6cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

test
\begin{figure}[h]% H is not an option
  \centering
%  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{test11.pdf}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{test11.pdf}
  \caption{Some data points with fitted curves.}
%  \centering% not needed here
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

Though your `test.11.pdf` isn't too large (47 k) that's the bottle neck. It takes time just to display test11.pdf separately. So it does take time, once you change the window size of the `Latex.pdf` (74 kB) created from it.

So, you have to improve the `test11` itself.

Blurs already seem to be included in test11, e.g. the blue dots are not pronounced. They start somewhere, they overlap somehow, the result looks bad, simple as that.

To compare, here is an excerpt from the created Latex.pdf, magnification 1200 % ... (zoomed vector graphics)

[image]